# Library csv has unexpected error

Tags: python, csv

I have the following csv file

```
name;address;city
John; Wellington; Washington
Paul; Oxford Street; Barcelona
```

is called, test.csv, and I want to read it using python, I wrote the following code:

```
import csv

with open('test.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader=csv.reader(csvfile, delimeter=';')
    for r in reader:
        print(r)
```

But I get the following error message

```
TypeError: 'delimeter' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

I do not know what is the problem, the documentation of csv says that delimeter is one of the parameters of the function.  I am using the following python distribution

```
Python 3.6.1 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:25:24) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's `delimiter`. You've got that spelling wrong

Answer (score 2):

It's `delimiter` and not `delimeter`. Simple typo.